# square bracket and the pair type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, generic-programming

I read a piece of code from a book but I do not really understand the grammar,

```
const auto& [local_min, local_max] = minmax(A[i], A[i+1]);
```

where `A` is `vector` of `int` and `local_min` and `local_max` are `int`.

I know `minmax` returns a `pair`, but what does the square brackets do, i.e.  `[local_min, local_max]`? I guess it is not for arrays here.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a C++17 extension for structured bindings. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: ...not really a good dupe, but the closest i could find